# Exporting article figures to beamer

Tags: beamer, thesis, beamerarticle

Is there some way to export or build a beamer presentation from only the figures from an article/book/thesis?

I would like to build a pdf set of slides from all the figures in my thesis, including the figure number referencing and the organizational structure of the Parts/Chapters/Sections/Subsection. I have written my doctoral thesis using latex with a special class of book.

I understand that there is a conversion from beamer to article, but I would like to go the other way around, and only include the figures with their captions.

Answer (score 3):

With the option `ignorenonframetext` you could basically use the main part of your thesis and wrap `frame`s around the figures. While `\section`s etc. are maintained all the other text between the images will be ignored.

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\begin{document}

\section{sec}

text text

\begin{frame}
    \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{text}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{text}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```